# toastr - want to add input inside toastr message - can this be done

Tags: toastr, angular16, ngx-toastr

I want to show a toastr message with an input box to ask for the users email if the data is too large so I can send via email. I've tried this but can't get it to work

```
 if (this.dataListTotal > 500) {
  // this.toastr.warning('Please add a filter!', 'Dataset is too big!', {
  this.toastr.warning('<div><input value="email" id="email"/></div>', 'Dataset is too big!', {
    enableHtml: true,
  });
}
```